# Iterate thru response and get a value via Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a specific value from the output below. I am trying to get the value for "package_path". I am trying to find the best way to do this. I tried `iteritems()` but it does not seem to provide the proper value output. Is there another way for me to do this?.. Thanks..

```
[{"name": "ZONE", "value": "zone01"}, 
 {"name": "VPCNetworkCIDRs", "value": "192.168.30.0/24"}, 
 {"name": "DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT", "value": "AWS"}, 
 {"name": "parameters_json", "value": "s3://my_folder/zone01/zone01.json"}, 
 {"name": "REGION", "value": "us-east-1"}, 
 {"name": "SECTOR", "value": ""}, 
 {"name": "package_path", "value": "s3://my_bucket/packages/my_app.1.0.2.0.pkg"}, 
 {"name": "component_type", "value": "WebApplication"}, 
 {"name": "PROFILE", "value": "dev"}]
```

Comment: `path = [b['value'] for b in a if b['name'] == 'package_path'][0]` is one way to find your value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider reformatting your data structure into a single dict. For example, using:

```
data = dict((item['name'], item['value']) for item in items)
```

Then:

```
print(data['package_path'])
```

will give you what you need, and similar for other items.

Answer (score 2):

Since what you have is a list of dictionaries, you must iterate over their `name` attributes to find the one that you want.

```
my_list = [{"name": "ZONE", "value": "zone01"}, {"name": "VPCNetworkCIDRs", "value": "192.168.30.0/24"},
 {"name": "DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT", "value": "AWS"},
 {"name": "parameters_json", "value": "s3://my_folder/zone01/zone01.json"}, {"name": "REGION", "value": "us-east-1"},
 {"name": "SECTOR", "value": ""}, {"name": "package_path", "value": "s3://my_bucket/packages/my_app.1.0.2.0.pkg"},
 {"name": "component_type", "value": "WebApplication"}, {"name": "PROFILE", "value": "dev"}]



package_path = None

# For each name/value pair in my_list...
for name_value in my_list:
    # If the name attribute is package_path, we found it
    if name_value['name'] == 'package_path':
        package_path = name_value['value']  # Store our variable
        break # Exit the loop

if package_path is None:
    print('Package path not found :(')
else:
    print(package_path)  # s3://my_bucket/packages/my_app.1.0.2.0.pkg
```

Comment: Interesting so when I run the code above, it works. But if I use the var thats actually storing the output instead of the my_list var I get the following "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"  I am trying to get the value from the "response_dump" var. I am using the following "ecs_env_var = response['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['environment']
response_dump = json.dumps(ecs_env_var)"

Comment: Actually referncing the "ecs_env_var " instead of the "response_dump" resolved the issue.  Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension.

```
[arg['value'] for arg in my_list if arg['name'] == 'package_path']
```